# Profile guided optimization for DLL's (intel compiler)

Tags: c, dll, icc

I have a C .dll file which I am running from C#. I recently compiled it with Intel C Compiler and I already see 25% speed-up over Visual Studio compiler (and almost 50% over MinGW).
Now I would like to try profile guided optimization. I understand that compiling with /prof-gen and then running the executable results in a file with dynamic profile information.
The problem is I don't have tests ready in my C program (and they would be cumbersome to write).
**My question is:**
Is it somehow possible to create .dyn file by compiling to .dll and then running it from c# level and then use it for  PGO with /prof-use ?

Any other information on using PGO with dlls are welcome :)

Comment: I have written tests for every part and I know how much time every part takes. I profiled it for a long time so please don't jump to conclusions like that. The problem is c# part does a lot of data conversion stuff and presenting stuff and it's much easier for me to use this than write all this stuff in C.

Comment: In the question you said you didn't write tests for the C code.

Comment: I don't have one test to run all the functions in exact proportions as they are usd like my c# does. Anyway the question is about how to use PGO in .dlls not about methodology of testing in general.